# Assigning value to member of a map through an iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to loop through a map and assign a value to elements within it:

```
typedef map<int,Node, less<int> >::const_iterator TopologyIter;

bool
RoutingManager::ActivateNewNode()
{
    TopologyIter iter;
    do
    {
        if(!iter->second.online)
        {
            iter->second.online = true;
            iter->second.connection = myConnection->newConnections.back();
            myConnection->newConnections.pop_back();
            return true; //all good
        }       

        iter++;

    }while (iter != topology.end());

    return false; //received a connection, but no more nodes to hand out
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> manager.cpp:91:24: error: assignment of member ‘Node::online’ in read-only object
>       iter->second.online = true;

This is my Node structure:

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include "nodecon.h"
typedef map<int,int, less<int> >::const_iterator NodeNeighborsIter;

struct Node
{
    int id;
    std::map<int,int> neighbors;
    bool online;

    struct NodeConnection connection;
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: For one, `iter` isn't assigned to *anything* before you attempt to dereference it.

Comment: `const_iterator` means the object it points to is `const` - can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

A `const_iterator` can't be used to modify the contents of the container. All values obtained by dereferencing a `const_iterator` are `const`.